# Dynamic Service Creation to Distribute Load

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric

## Background

The problem we're facing is that we are doing video encoding and want to distribute the load to multiple nodes in the cluster.

We would like to constrain the number of video encoding jobs on a particular node to some maximum value. We would also like to have small video encoding jobs sent to a certain grouping of nodes in the cluster, and long video encoding jobs sent to another grouping of nodes in the cluster.

The idea behind this is to help maintain fairness amongst clients by partitioning the large jobs into a separate pool of nodes. This helps ensure that the small video encoding jobs are not blocked / throttled by a single tenant running a long encoding job.

## Using Service Fabric

We plan on using an ASF service for the video encoding. With this in mind we had an idea of dynamically creating a service for each job that comes in. Placement constraints could then be used to determine which pool of nodes a job would run in. Custom metrics based on memory usage, CPU usage ... could be used to limit the number of active jobs on a node.

With this method the node distributing the jobs would have to poll whether a new service could currently be created that satisfies the placement constraints and metrics.

## Questions

- What happens when a service can't be placed on a node? (Using CreateServiceAsync I assume?)
- Will this polling be prohibitively expensive?
- Our video encoding executable is packaged along with the service which is approximately 80MB. Will this make the spinning up of a new service take a long time? (Minutes vs seconds)
- As an alternative to this we could use a reliable queue based system, where the large jobs pool pulls from one queue and the small jobs pool pulls from another queue. This seems like the simpler way, but I want to explore all options to make sure I'm not missing out on some of the features of Service Fabric. Is there another better way you would suggest?

Answer (score 1):

I have no experience with placement constraints and dynamic services, so I can't speak to that.

The polling of the perf counters isn't terribly expensive, that being said it's not a free operation. A one second poll interval shouldn't cause any huge perf impact while still providing a decent degree of resolution.

The service packages get copied to each node at deployment time rather than when services get spun up, so it'll make the deployment a bit slower but not affect service creation.

You're going to want to put the job data in reliable collections any way you structure it, but the question is how. One idea I just had that might be worth considering is making the job processing service a partitioned service and base your partitioning strategy based off encoding job size and/or tenant so that large jobs from the same tenant get stuck in the same queue, and smaller jobs for others go elsewhere.

As an aside, one thing I've dealt with in the past is SF remoting limits the size of the messages sent and throws if its too big, so if your video files are being passed from service to service you're going to want to consider a paging strategy for inter service communication.